# How do I solve for simple pendulum?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, euler-lagrange-equation

For example, I have the Euler-Lagrange equation for a simple pendulum:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+\frac{g}{l}\theta &=& 0
\end{eqnarray*}

How do I find $\theta$? I know that one approach is to find the roots of the characteristic equation $\lambda^2+\frac{g}{l}\lambda=0$ and then write the solution in the form $y=c_1e^{\lambda_1x}+c_2e^{\lambda_2x}$, but the roots of such an equation are $0$ and $-\frac{g}{l}$, while the answer seems to entail some sines and cosines. Any ideas?

I'm looking into an ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:

Two functions will solve the equation in question:
$$y(t)=\cos\left(\sqrt \frac{g}{l}t\right)$$ and $$y(t)=\sin\left(\sqrt \frac{g}{l}t\right)$$

The general solution is a linear combination of both sine and cosine, i.e.:
$$y(t)=A\cos\left(\sqrt \frac{g}{l}t\right) + B\sin\left(\sqrt \frac{g}{l}t\right)$$

And then this can be rewritten as
$$y(t)=A\sin\left(\sqrt \frac{g}{l}t+\theta\right)$$

Can anyone give some intuition into this?

Wouldn't it also make sense to have cosine instead of sine because this is describing general harmonic oscillation path (i.e. $y(t)=Acos(\omega t+\theta)$, where A is the amplitude, $\omega$ is the angular frequency and $\theta$ is a phase change? This equation would then imply that $\sqrt \frac{g}{l}$ is the angular frequency? Is this the right thinking?

Comment: The characteristic equation is $\;\lambda^2+\dfrac gl=0$.  There's no term in $\lambda$.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the heads up! This means I must use the complex form of the characteristic equation.

Comment: @JimM: no, the answer contains $\sqrt{g/l}$, not $g/l$. You can solve for $c_1,c_2$ by imposing initial conditions on $\theta$ and $d\theta/dt$.

Comment: @enzotib: I see, but then how can we rewrite $c_1cos \sqrt \frac{g}{l}t+c_2sin \sqrt \frac {g}{l}t$ into just $csin\sqrt \frac{g}{l}t$?

Comment: @Winther, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Yes $\sqrt{g/l} = \omega$ is the angular velocity, or said differently the period of osscillation is $T = 2\pi \sqrt{l/g}$. There is no difference between $\sin(x + A)$ and $\cos(x + B)$ when $A$ and $B$ are free constants since $\sin(x + \pi/2) = \cos(x)$ thus you can use either one to specify the solution. The constants are fixed by imposing the initial conditions (initial position and velocity).